# Why elem_match is returning 0 elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am trying to get one record result from a collection of objects, but after following the Mongoid documentation I don't know what more to try.

I have this single element:

```
 > contacts
 => #<Contact _id: 55ace6bc6xx, device_fields: {"app_id"=>"55ace6bc65195efc8200xxxx"}, created_at: 2015-07-20 12:17:00 
    UTC, updated_at: 2015-07-20 12:17:00 UTC, name_first: "Kory", 
    name_last: "Funk", ...>
```

this list of matchers:

```
> apps = []
> apps << App.where(id: "55ace6bc65195efc8200xxxx").first.id
=> ["55ace6bc65195efc8200xxxx"]
```

And this code trying to get the elements that match:

```
> contacts.elem_match(device_fields: {:app_id.in => apps }).to_a
=> []
> contacts.elem_match(device_fields: { "app_id": "55ace6bc65195efc8200xxxx"}).to_a
=> []
```

Why is it returning an empty array it there is one that matches?

Comment: Could you try `contacts.elem_match(device_fields: { "app_id": apps.first}).to_a` ?

Comment: Yes, same result. I tried this and lots of possible combinations... I couldn't get the correct response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official [mongodb manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field

And you are trying to use it with the hash field so you basically misunderstood this selection. So there is no object that matches.

Instead of it you should do:

```
contacts.where(:'device_fields.app_id'.in => apps).to_a
```

Comment: oh yes! I was replacing a `has_many` association (hash) to a `has_one` and I was trying to refactor the old `elem_match`. That's true, it's not a hash anymore. Now all seems clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can not achieve to resolve this with `match_elem` method, so finally I decided to make it through `and`.  I am not very happy with this solution and I still don't understand why `match_elem` is not returning records, but at least I have found a solution to unblock this feature.

```
contacts.and(:device_fields.exists => true,
             :device_fields.nin => ['', nil], 
             :"device_fields.app_id".in => apps).to_a
```

Comment: You don't need the first two clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `elemMatch` here. It's for finding object array elements by partial matches (where you don't need full object equality, but only one or several fields)

This should work for your case.

```
contacts.where('device_fields.app_id' => {'$in' => apps})
```